# SharePoint server 2019 on-premise , onedrive and ms office 2019 pro plus Unsubscribe

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem, 2019, onedrive

I have a SharePoint server 2019 on-premise 16.0.10404.20003 version, with installed onedrive.

Onedrive client on PC 23.226.1031.0003 version, that connected to SharePoint onedrive via AD account.

I can upload and download files via explorer, everything works fine. I can edit files via office online server on-premise individually or in collaborative editing. But I can't edit existing files, or create new one in Onedrive locally on PC in ms office 2019 pro plus.

When I try to save file it says just "File not saved". No errors in System ivents on pc or server.

Please tell me what could be the reason, all my guesswork is over.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried resetting OneDrive?

Control Panel > User Accounts > Credential Manager > Windows Credentials, and removing any "OneDrive" credentials. Then, right-click the OneDrive icon > Settings > Account > Unlink this PC > Unlink this account.

After that, you can try to sync the OneDrive changes by running the "Onedrive.exe /reset" command in run.

Comment: Yes, that's doesn't help.